# Failed to find module in a python project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I got a python project recently and failed to launch it. It is a gunicorn backend application. When I use below command to launch the server:

```
gunicorn --pythonpath api app:application development --reload
```

I got below error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'require_json'
```

The `require_json` is an internal module in this project. The project structure is like:

```
api/app.py
middlewares/require_json.py
middlewares/__init__.py
```

In `api/app.py`, it imports `require_json` by this code:

`from middlewares import  json_translator`

but it doesn't find the `require_json` module. Is this anything to do with my system path? I am using `MacOS`.

Comment: What is this project you are trying to run? Did you try asking the project author for help?

Comment: I not sure a package named `require_json` exists. But I'm sure `require json` looks like a Ruby equivalent to Python's `import json`.

Comment: @Arount Exactly. Or it maybe the case that the project people didn't upload `require_json` to PyPI.

Comment: Thanks for the response. After some debug, I found that the `require_json` is defined inside this project. And I have revised my question. could you please have a look at.